# Java Axis2 An unexpected error has occurred. 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: java, web-services

> WAB0135E An unexpected error has occurred. 407 Proxy Authentication
>   Required

The above message appears when i try to launch my WSDL from web service launch explorer but it cant reach the tomcat server although java application class main test it works fine but not on server the project working on my home eclipse but not on my work eclipse ; i included all jar,axis2,jdbc and etc.. like home but gives me that message . **one thing to mention i have a proxy set on my eclipse at work .**

Comment: actually i work on local host so i dont need proxy i added it to download plugins but it worked when i uncheck the proxy on local host from --window-->preferences-->networkconnections --localhost because i only need it on http :) [see how link.......](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-net-preferences.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually i work on local host so i dont need **proxy** i added it to download plugins but it worked when i uncheck the proxy on local host from

`--window-->preferences-->networkconnections --localhost`

because i only need it on http

[link Network Connections eclipse how to configure](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-net-preferences.htm)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the error occured because your internet connection is behind a proxy. The 'network configuration' section of the Axis document shows how to configure client proxy: http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/client-side-axis.html. Try configuring it with your authentication credential